# Laravel 5 - Grouping, Counting and Outputting eager loaded relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Pretty new to Laravel and am trying to build a web app to help me run my Martial Arts business.  Thanks so much for the help!

## Overview:

The webapp allows me to create *Lessons* which I can add *Students* and *Techniques* to.  Each *Technique* can have multiple *Variations* of the technique but not all *Variations* have to be added to a lesson.

Once those are added, I want to display all of the Lessons/Techniques/Variations on one page for the student.

[image: What I want to accomplish]

### Controllers:

HomeController.php:

```
public function studentProfile($id)
{


     $students = Student::with(['lesson.technique.variation'])->where('id',$id)->get();



    return view('techniques', compact('students'));  
}
```

### View:

technique.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard.dashboard')

@section('content')
<main class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">

@foreach ($students as $student)
  <h1>{{ $student->name }}</h1>
@endforeach 





 <h2>Fundamentals</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Mount</th>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Guard</th>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Side Mount</th>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Standing</th>
              <th>#</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>1. Trap and Roll</strong><br>- Standard<br>- Headlock<br>- Punch Block</td>
              <td><br>3<br>4<br>3</td>
              <td><strong>1. Punch Block Stage 1-4</strong><br>- Stage 1<br>- Stage 2<br>- Stage 3<br>- Stage 4</td>
              <td><br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1</td>
              <td><strong>1. Positional Control</strong><br>- Roll Prevention<br>- Guard Prevention<br>- Mount Transition</td>
              <td><br>1<br>1<br>1</td>
              <td><strong>1. Clinch</strong><br>- Aggressive<br>- Conservative</td>
              <td><br>1<br>1</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
     </main>
@endsection
```

### Models:

Techniques (belongsToMany::Lesson, hasMany::Variation):

- id,
- name,
- category,
- subcategory,
- level,
- timestamps

Variations (belongsTo::Technique, belongsTo::Lesson):

- id,
- name,
- technique_id,
- timestamps

Students (belongsTo::User, belongsToMany::Lesson):

- id,
- name,
- birthdate,
- user_id,
- timestamps

Lessons (belongsToMany::Technique, belongsToMany::Student, belongsToMany::Variation):

- id,
- name,
- status,
- timestamps

Each has the correct pivot table (eg: lesson_variations).

I can dd($students) and see all the nested relationships but I am having a very hard time understanding how I can groupBy and count the results.  I want to groupBy multiple ways including:

- I want to Group all the Techniques by Level (Fundamentals, Advanced).
- Then I want to display all the Techniques by Category and then SubCategory and finally,
- I want to count all the variations that relate to the technique so if there are 10 lessons and in those 10 lessons, you did Technique trap and roll 8 times and the variation Standard 6 times it would show:

Fundamentals:

Category

Sub Category

Technique

Technique's Variations Count over all lessons.

[What I want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqlzX.png)

## Thank you!

Thank you so much for your help!  I really appreciate it!  Once this is done the webapp should be finished it's first version and will help save me hours of work per week!

### Edit:

[image: Technique DB Table]

Comment: I've not read your entire question yet. But one thing I immediately noticed was this line from your controller - `$students = Student::with(['lesson', 'lesson.technique', 'lesson.technique.variation'])->where('id',$id)->get();`. This can be written far more succinctly as follows, if you like - `$student = Student::with('lesson.technique.variation')->find($id);`.

Comment: Can I check that you understand the difference between `group by` and `count`? From the screenshot, it looks more like you want a count of each technique / variation, rather than to group by each (thus eliminating duplicates)? Can you confirm?

Comment: Thanks @fubar!   That is good to know!

Comment: @fubar I think I understand.  Basically, I want to group all the category/sub category for the techniques so when I foreach them in the view they come out in the order I want and then count the # of variations for each of those techniques.

Comment: Can you just explain where `mount`, `guard`, etc come into this? Are they lessons, categories or subcategories?

Comment: @fubar yes, sorry I understand how confusing this is from an outsider looking in.

Mount and guard are both Technique->category

I have added another image at the bottom edit section that includes my DB and the technique's DB.

Comment: tl;dr... put only relevant code

Comment: Hi Elias.  Thanks for the response.  I actually thought I was adding relevant code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm finding it difficult to understand and work with your data when I don't have it in front of me. I do not think you can achieve what you're trying to do with queries alone. I think you're going to have to do some manipulation using Laravel Collections (`groupBy` and `count`) to get the output you require.

Comment: Thanks @Fubar.  I spoke to someone who was also quite helpful and I am going to try to seperate all the queries and then see if I can store it into an Array instead.

I put the code onto github if you are interested: https://github.com/lem72/StudentTracker2

Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.